# PLSQL Trigger: before insert

Tags: oracle, plsql, triggers

Am trying to write a trigger which has to restrict for zero salary before insertion.
I have written but its not working. I am getting an error as trigger is invalid and failed re validation.

Code:

```
create or replace trigger emp_sal
  before insert or update on employee
  referencing new as new old as old
  for each row
begin
     if :new.salary<=0 then
         raise_application_error (-20999,’salary is zero’);
     end if;
end;
/
```

Please let me know where the problem is. Thank you

Comment: Why not use a check constraint instead?

Answer (score 0):

Your code is okay. The only problem I can imagine is that you were using the wrong character for the single quotes in ’salary is zero’.

Run `show errors` right after you created the trigger (assuming you're uning sqlplus)

But I agree with zerkms. This is a case for a check constraint.